# How do I see formaly that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n|^p = |f|^p$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of functions s.t $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$, where $f_n : X  \rightarrow  \mathbb R$.

How do I see formaly that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n|^p = |f|^p$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$ ?

I see that for any $\epsilon > 0, \ x \in X$ we can find $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$ which mean $f_n(x) \le \epsilon + f(x)$ or $f_n \ge  f(x) - \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x\in X$, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, we have $|f_n|^p(x)\to|f|^p(x)$, since $g(x)=|x|, h(x)=x^p$ are continuous functions.

Hence  $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n|^p =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n|^p = = |f|^p$.

Comment: I see, but how can you rewrite $\liminf$ to $\lim$ ?

Comment: @user111854 For convergent sequence, $\liminf x_n=\lim x_n $.

Comment: I've seen this theorem stated if $(x_n)$ is bounded, how can one say this is true here ?

Comment: Oww, I see it now. A convergent sequence is bounded....